# C# windows appication Evento: CLR20r3 ao iniciar a aplicação

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Eu criei uma aplicação windows forms c# .net 4.5, no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento funciona perfeitamente, mas, quando eu coloco o release no ambiente do cliente, da o seguinte erro ao iniciar:

```
Descrição
    Stopped working

Assinatura do problema:
Nome do Evento de Problema: CLR20r3
Assinatura do Problema 01:  hmb.consplus.ivw.exe
Assinatura do Problema 02:  1.0.0.0
Assinatura do Problema 03:  55e8b96b
Assinatura do Problema 04:  System.Data
Assinatura do Problema 05:  4.0.30319.18408
Assinatura do Problema 06:  52311175
Assinatura do Problema 07:  25c0
Assinatura do Problema 08:  27
Assinatura do Problema 09:  System.Data.Entity.Core.Entity
Versão do sistema operacional:  6.0.6001.2.1.0.274.10
Identificação da Localidade:    1046
```

O que devo fazer para solucionar esse problema?

Eu já desinstalei e instalei o .net 4.5, mas o erro persiste.

**Atualização**

Realizei alguns testes na estrutura do meu projeto, e percebi que o problema esta no arquivo de configuração `App.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>    
        <add name="CONSPLUSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CONSPLUS.csdl|res://*/CONSPLUS.ssdl|res://*/CONSPLUS.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=CALLPLUS_VW;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Admin55*;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

O model do entity framework, esta em um outro projeto, e quando o removo a referência desse projeto do projeto principal, o erro não ocorre mais.

**Versões**:
.Net: 4.5.1;
Entity Framework: 6.1.3;

**APP.Config** - Do projeto que tem o E.F

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="CONSPLUSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CONSPLUS.csdl|res://*/CONSPLUS.ssdl|res://*/CONSPLUS.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=<host>;initial catalog=CALLPLUS_VW;persist security info=True;user id=<id>;password=<senha>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
           </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Windows?

Comment: Windows server 2008

Comment: Tu estás referenciando alguma dll que não esteja entre as padrões do `.net`?

Comment: Eu uso o Entity Framework 6.1

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nessa](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7264879/revisions) resposta. Talvez isso te ajude.

Comment: Mesmo assim, continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Verifica as versões do framework que tuas dependências estão utilizando *References > Escolher a referência > Properties > Runtime Version*. Olha primeiramente das *System.Data*. Parece que alguma das tuas referências está tentando usar outra versão do `.net`.